# How to disable wrapping lines in nano?

Tags: line-breaks, word-wrap, nano

My nano did not wrap long lines automatically at first, they just kept going. I do not know what I did but now the automatic wrapping is enabled.

I want to know how to reconfigure nano to disable automatic line wrapping, this has bothered me a lot.

I've seen the `nano -w` command that it comes without wrapping, but what I want is to disable it by default and run nano without having to worry about wrapping.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To change persistent settings for `nano`, we can edit the user-specific *.nanorc* file (*/home/user/.nanorc*). This file contains configuration settings that `nano` loads on start-up.

To disable line-wrapping, we need to specify the `nowrap` directive. Add this line to *.nanorc*:

```
set nowrap
```

We may need to create this file if it doesn't exist. For more information about the available settings in this file, see the [*.nanorc* man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/nanorc):

```
$ man nanorc
```

Comment: I made a request to change the default or add a warning: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?55067

Comment: A brief discussion took place in http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/nano-devel/2018-11/msg00057.html.  People seem generally in favour of having `set nowrap` by default, but no decisions seem to have been made.

Comment: Good suggestion @mwfearnley. I think some distributions already build nano with `nowrap` and other less-obnoxious defaults.

Comment: FWIW, just `set nowrap` didn't do it for me, but adding `set softwrap` as well did. From [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/464614/81185).

Comment: None of nowrap/softwrap works. Nano 4.8, Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2):

For others like me that hit this question from google and only want to disable wrapping temporarily, press <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>.

That toggles "Hard wrapping of overlong lines".